# feature telnet server not available in windows 10

Tags: server, windows-10, telnet

In the features of windows 7 we have both telnet client and telnet server. But in windows 10 telnet server is not available, Can anyone please guide on how to install it? And I am also aware that we can use ssh instead of telnet.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft deprecated Telnet Servers in Windows Server 2012 R2, and subsequently in Windows 10.

Telnet is considered completely insecure these days, because it sends everything across the wire in plain text, so they removed it.

Since you'd need to install a [3rd party Telnet server](http://www.georgiasoftworks.com/products/uts/overview.php), you should (instead) consider installing a SSH server. Similar abilities and results, but SSH is generally considered secure.

Perhaps check out this Serverfault question for some suggested SSH servers:

[What is a good SSH server to use on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)

(Answer from @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 found [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/1106146/server-manager-for-telnet))

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a tad late to this feed, but I have used the [GSW Telnet Server](https://www.georgiasoftworks.com/telnet-server-windows) and [SSH Server](https://www.georgiasoftworks.com/ssh-server-windows) and they have been great. They claim to be the most secure SSH on the market and I have never had any issues with data security at all.
They do have 24/7 support and can help with installation if there are any difficulties.

Hope this helps - Ben